# No line separation when sending an iCalendar to web page. Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, icalendar, ical4j

I am trying to send an iCalendar to webpage but when I send it there is no line separation and it is not considered as correct iCalendar format. If I send iCalendar format its just JSON format. And if its `calendar.toString()` there is no line separation. How can I send it in correct format?

```
Calendar calendar = iCalendarService.getCalendar();
System.out.println(calendar); //Correct format in console
return ResponseEntity.ok(calendar.toString()); //No line separation
//return ResponseEntity.ok(calendar); // Json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is defined at a Controller method level, try to set the media type to `text/calendar`:

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/your/path",
    produces = "text/calendar"
)
```

Alternatively, you can try the following return line:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(new MediaType("text", "calendar")).body(calendar.toString());
```